# CListView: Endless appending of parameters in pagination URL's

Tags: yii, pagination, clistview

I'm using modified URL manager with embedding language information in the URL address.
This is my config:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'class'=>'cms.components.UrlManager',
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<language:(sk|en)>/*' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

And URL manager:

```
class UrlManager extends CUrlManager
{
    public function createUrl($route, $params = array(), $ampersand = '&')
    {
        if (!isset($params['language']))
        {
            if (Yii::app()->user->hasState('language'))
            {
                Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->user->getState('language');
            }
            else if (isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['language']))
            {
                Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->request->cookies['language']->value;
            }
            $params['language'] = Yii::app()->language;
        }

        return parent::createUrl($route, $params, $ampersand);
    }
}
```

CListView code:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'viewData'=>array('asset'=>$this->layout_asset),
    'dataProvider'=>$provider,
    'itemView'=>'common.blocks.sportlistview.item_render',
    'summaryText'=>'',
    'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
    'enablePagination'=> true,
    'enableSorting'=>false,
    'sortableAttributes'=>array(),
    'template'=>'{items}{pager}',
    'emptyText' => '',
));
```

This is my current behavior of links in pagination (with description):

```
http://example.com/web/page/render/sk/slug/test-page                                            /* Original URL */
http://example.com/web/page/render/sk/slug/test-page/sk/slug/test-page/                         /* URL of the first page in pagination on the original URL */
http://example.com/web/page/render/sk/slug/test-page/sk/slug/test-page//page/2                  /* URL of the second page in pagination on the original URL */
http://example.com/web/page/render/sk/ajax/yw1/slug/test-page/sk/slug/test-page/sk              /* URL of the first page in pagination on the second URL */
http://example.com/web/page/render/sk/ajax/yw1/slug/test-page/sk//test-page/sk/yw1/slug/page/2  /* URL of the second page in pagination on the first page modified URL */
http://example.com/web/page/render/sk/ajax/yw1/slug/test-page/sk/ajax/test-page/sk/yw1/slug
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# PAGE REDIRECT TO WEB FOLDER
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/resources/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1 [NC,L,NS]

# RESOURCES REDIRECT
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^static.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/resources/$1 [NC,L,NS]

# ADMIN REDIRECT
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^admin.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ backend/$1 [NC,L,NS]
```

Main application is located in `www.example.com/web`.

What should I do to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Can you please add your `.htaccess` with the rewrite rules.

Comment: It seems, that you had a fail in your .htaccess witch is used to hide the index.php

Comment: I have added my `.htaccess` file content.

Comment: What did `var_dump($_GET)` returns you? I had this problem once, but i don't know how i fixed it :-S